# iPhone Background Threads vs. Timers Performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mobile

One of our requirment can be implemented either by running a NSTimer every 30 mins or a background thread/job, which polls specific application 'state' every one minute.

But I am wondering how CPU intensive this background job compared to NSTimer, if NOT much of a difference then we will go for background threads/jobs.

Thanks

Comment: Note that background CPU time is only granted to a few limited types of iOS apps, or for only a few minutes of the app being in the background, then the app will be frozen and not run until the user brings it to the foreground.

Comment: To echo what hotpaw2 says, if you are not one of these limited types of apps then forget it. Have you researched that area first? Look at UI Background Modes (and you can only use these if they are central to your app, you can't use them just to run in the background).

Answer (score 0):

Threads are very lightweight.

In fact you could very well do the NSTimer polling on main thread and then use GCD to perform the actual work on a private serial queue (on another thread) using an inline block. That way your code remains very readable while you do not sacrifice any performance.

Note that NSTimer does not guarantee exact timing precision, but I assume that is not important.